# Python Regex to split logfile on date string

Tags: python, regex

I have some data which is irregularly formatted (which I cannot control) and single events sometimes span across multiple lines. My strategy is to remove all the newlines and control characters scattered throughout the data to create a single stream, and then split this back apart based upon the consistent date/time string which is always at the beginning of a new valid event.

I started with the following regex to accomplish this:

```
new_data = "".join(ch for ch in attachment_data if unicodedata.category(ch)[0]!="C")
new_data2 = re.split('([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s[AaPp][Mm];)',new_data)
```

However my delimiter (the date/time string) ends up in another element in the resulting list. I need it to be included with all the data between it and the next delimiter. I've been searching around for solutions but haven't come across something that works.

So instead of:

```
['9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;', "Last, First;FRONT DOOR;Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 'FRONT DOOR' (IN).]
```

I'm looking for:

```
['9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;Last, First;FRONT DOOR;Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 'FRONT DOOR' (IN).]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and include the original log file without any formatting changes made by you.  Then, show us clear output which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use positive `lookahead` :

```
import re

text = """
9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;Last, First;FRONT DOOR;Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 'FRONT DOOR' (IN).1.
9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;Last, First;FRONT DOOR;
Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 'FRONT DOOR' (IN).2.
9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;Last, First;FRONT DOOR;Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 
'FRONT DOOR' (IN).3.
"""
# match d/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss
date_pattern = r'[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}\s(?:[0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0-9]{1,2}\s(?:am|pm);'
# extract text begin by date pattern and followed by date pattern or end of text
ptrn = r"(?i){date_pattern}.+?(?={date_pattern}|$)".format(date_pattern=date_pattern)
result = re.findall(ptrn, text.replace('\n', ''))
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

ouput:

```
9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;Last, First;FRONT DOOR;Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 'FRONT DOOR' (IN).1.
9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;Last, First;FRONT DOOR;Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 'FRONT DOOR' (IN).2.
9/26/2019 6:30:20 PM;Last, First;FRONT DOOR;Admitted 'Last, First' (Card: 123456)   at 'FRONT DOOR' (IN).3.
```